# Representing graph data in two different formats in MS Excel 2010

Tags: excel, graph, numbers, excel-2010, percentage

I’m using MS Excel 2010.
I made a line graph based on some data I have. My supervisor suggested me adding a table that shows the number values of the readings underneath the graph. Fortunately, Excel provides this feature from the “Design” tab, and then selecting the layout that has the line graph and a table underneath. 

However, I want to show the graph data (y-axis) in percentage but the table values in numbers.

As an attempt to do this, I selected the area of the y-axis data (right click) -> Format axis -> Number -> Percentage. It works in changing it to percentage values but the problem is that it makes it as if multiplied by 10 (i.e. I need it to show the percentages as 0%, 20%,…, 100%, etc. instead of 0%, 200%,…, 1000%, etc. I failed in adding a suitable “Format Code” to solve my problem.

I need your help, please!
Thanks

Screenshots:
My graph:
http://www.mediafire.com/view/d1wjajf66dt53xr/graph2.jpg
The window options
http://www.mediafire.com/view/cc2o5itwdd8yye5/Format_axis_window.jpg

Comment: Wondering if anyone has thoughts about my question?

Comment: is the value of 5 equal to 5% or to 50%?

Comment: could you please answer my question just above this comment? Otherwise it is not clear what you are expecting to see.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume the number 5 represents 5% (and not 50%, see my question under the OP).

Then you can use the following custom format for the axis:

`0"%"`

if you have decimals just add those:

`0.0"%"`

Comment: Thank you for the response, but, unfortunately, the number isn't equal to the percentage because the percentage was rounded!

Comment: I am very sorry, but I fail to get any specific direction from this comment (in how to improve the answer). Could you please answer my question under your Original Post so I can understand what the expected end result should be (and NOT what it shouldn't be).